# Can you purchase DLC for pre-owned games?

Tags: ps3, psn, castlevania-lords-of-shadow

Are you able to purchase downloadable content for a PS3 game if the game you have is pre-owned?  The game in question is Castlevania Lords of Shadow 2 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if a pre-owned physical copy of a game can use DLC that is bought from the PSN store? Yes, absolutely.